# mouse.set_pos() not changing mouse position when using mousemouse.set_visible(False)

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I'm displaying an image instead of a mouse cursor. My code works perfectly until i added this line `mouse.set_visible(False)` at the start of the code.

The issue is that `mouse.set_pos()` is no longer changing my mouse position.

let me give you an example....

```
mouse.set_pos(screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height() / 2)
start_pos = (screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height() / 2)
print(mouse.get_pos() == start_pos)
```

The print returns `False` as `mouse.get_pos()` hasnt changed.

Note: I know that `mouse.set_pos()` isnt instant however it is not working when I use `mouse.set_visible(False)`. Also, I just figured outt, it isn't mouse.set_pos() that isn't working it is mouse.get_pos()

Comment: You already wrote what command caused this. So, what is your question?

Comment: How do I solve this with out getting rid of  `mouse.set_visible(False)` ? I have to include it because I dont want to display two mouse cursors

Comment: Do have an event loop?

Comment: yes, just didn't include it because I didn't think it would be helpful

Comment: Does it work when you call `pygame.event.pump()` before `mouse.get_pos()`?

Comment: no, It still prints/behaves the same

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about mouse.set_pos, but I do know that you don’t have to hide the cursor to use an image as a cursor.

In fact, in pygame 2.0.1 and above, you can use a Surface as the cursor itself.

pygame.mouse.set_cursor(hotspot, surface)

Where hotspot defines the center position of the cursor (int, int), and surface is a pygame.Surface.

Doc: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_cursor

Comment: I cant do that (for my program). I need to be able to freeze the cursor  (not all the time), but still be able to get mouse movement.